# auto template parameters: g++ 7.3 vs clang++ 6.0 : Which compiler is correct?

Tags: c++, g++, clang++, c++17

Two compilers produce different results for this code example.
Clang generates two different types. G++ uses same type for `fu` and `fi`.
Which one is standard compliant?

```
#include <iostream>

template< auto IVAL>
struct foo {
    decltype(IVAL) x = -IVAL;
};

int main()
{
    foo<10u> fu;
    foo<10> fi;
    std::cout << fi.x << " " << fu.x << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

g++-7.3 output:

> 4294967286 4294967286

clang-6.0 output:

> -10 4294967286

Comment: This is [gcc bug 79092](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79092).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

gcc is wrong here, these are clearly two distinct types.

And to confirm - this bug is fixed in gcc 8.0.1

[Sample code](http://wandbox.org/permlink/waO9L0kaKw7C5teP)